# Spring MVC mapping Guava Multimap

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping, guava, multimap

My controller can't map a Google Guava `Multimap` coming from the frontend. I send from my Javascript this object:

```
{1:[true,false], 2:[false,true], ...}.
```

If I use a standard

```
java.util.Map<Long, List<Boolean>>
```

everything works fine. But not with the Guava `Multimap`. Do I have to configure Spring to use some custom converter, or what is the problem?

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = CotrollerKonstanten.JSON_UTF8)
public long myMethod(@RequestBody MappingDto mappingDto) {
  //...
}
```

My exception is:

> ```
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: 
>   Can not construct instance of com.google.common.collect.Multimap, problem:
>   abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
> at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4b9c2db; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: ...myClass); 
> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
>   Can not construct instance of com.google.common.collect.Multimap, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
> ```

Comment: Please be more specific: show us your code (controller, converter) and an exception you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you [register the Guava module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava)? By default, Jackson (and hence Spring) does not support serializing or deserializing to Guava datatypes.

The Guava module may or may not work for you depending on what implementation of `Multimap` you want -- not all datatypes are implemented.

Comment: Ahh, that is the reason then, I think. I do not have the module in my pom. I thought it would work out of the box :-) Thank you.