# How do i send a post request with Google guava Multi-map data using rest template Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate, multimap

I have a multimap. When I try to send the data over to the backend-server from my frontend-server using restTemplate, it returns a "500 Internal Server Error" error code. It works for normal Map from the java.util.Map class. How do I configure restTemplate so that I send Google guava multimap data over?

This is my frontend-server code in spring boot.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

...

                try
                {
                    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    List<MediaType> acceptList = new ArrayList<>();
                    acceptList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    headers.setAccept(acceptList);

                    Multimap<String, byte[]> arrayMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
                    arrayMap.put("test", "hello".getBytes());
                    arrayMap.put("title", "meow".getBytes());
                    arrayMap.put("body", "A powerful tool for building web apps.".getBytes());

                    HttpEntity<Multimap<String, byte[]>> uploadEntity = new HttpEntity<>(arrayMap, headers);
                    ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.postForEntity(uri, uploadEntity, String.class);
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
                catch (HttpClientErrorException e)
                {
                    /**
                     *
                     * If we get a HTTP Exception display the error message
                     */
                    logger.error("error http client:  " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    logger.error("error:  " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

This is my Backend-server controller where it recevies the incoming data from my frontend-server.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
...
    @PostMapping(path="/rh2lev", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String setup(@RequestBody Multimap<String, byte[]> uploadIndex)
    {
        System.out.println(uploadIndex);
        return "everything ok";
    }
```

Comment: `500 internal Server Error` indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition(https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6). So at first you have to check whether your 'backend-server' can handle your 'encrypted data'.

Comment: You are right I guess but I'm not sure what are the changes that needs to be made to by backend-server. For some reason, it works for normal java map datatype but not for google guava multimap :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this error occurs on serializing `Multimap` objects into JSON string or deserializing JSON string into `Multimap` objects. Spring usually does JSON serialization/deserialization by using Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Jackson `ObjectMapper` can do JSON serialization/deserialization of `java.util.Map` objects by default but can't `com.google.common.collect.Multimap` objects.

So you need to configure a custom serializer in 'frontend-server' and also configure a custom deserializer in 'backend-server'. I think you can achieve this by using [jackson-datatype-guava](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/tree/master/guava).

**Example**

Configurations for your 'frontend-server' and 'backend-server'

(pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

(Spring Boot's configuration)

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurer  {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer guavaModuleCustomizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.modules(new GuavaModule());
        };
    }
}
```

**Related Question**

[Spring MVC mapping Guava Multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323594/spring-mvc-mapping-guava-multimap)

**For More Information**

[“How-to” Guides 4.3. Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper - Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)
[Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper - Baeldung blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)
[Jackson – Custom Serializer - Baeldung blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)
[Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson - Baeldung blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)